# How to properly make a header for a C function that receives a matrix

Tags: c, gcc, matrix, compilation, header

I'm trying to compile a C function that receives an static matrix and i want to make a header file for it. How should i define it? I tried this but i'm getting conflicting types error.

This is my header file

`nodo* construirArbol(int,int ,float **,nodo *,int);`

This is the "header" in the .c file

`nodo* construirArbol(int filas,int columnas,float matriz[][columnas],nodo *n,int iterador){`

I've tried this but i don't know if its a correct solution

`nodo* construirArbol(int,int c,float [][c],nodo *,int);`
Both of two first arguments are the rows and colums of the matrix

All help is welcome

Comment: Make them identical. Then program accordingly. Or program and then make them identical. No use in having prototypes different than function heads.

Comment: So the third piece of code is correct then? Thanks for answering!

Comment: It will make it easier to answer your question if you provide relevant compiler output to indicate the errors. What happened when you tried the solution at the end?

Comment: The compiler says conflicitng type error between the header and the .c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use square brackets to represent a matrix as a parameter for the function. On the other hand, when it comes to the matrix manipulations in the function definition feel free to use ones.

Comment: Is this a resolution to the issue or merely a commentary about the code?

Comment: So i better use asterisks?

Comment: Yeah,just use asterisks.